# htaccess help to reset

Tags: apache

How can I reset the .htaccess file? It was working at first then I made a change but when I saw that the change I made wasn't working, I immediately uploaded the original file. Then my site is stuck. I always get two www in front of my file. I need help to fix this. THank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In order for apache to see the changes you made to your .htaccess file, you just need to restart Apache, using `/etc/init.d/httpd restart` or `/etc/init.d/apache2` (Debian).

Comment: Thank you! But I can only access through cpanel and my host hasn't replied to me for days. Is there any way I can restart it?

Comment: I don't know (I've never used cpanel). When I searched, I happened across this: http://forums.cpanel.net/f5/restarting-apache-60364.html I hope it helps.